# I got my drive "bitlocker encrypted" by enterprise admins. Will this prevent me to share docs with my collaborators?

Tags: disk-encryption, bitlocker

I admit I don't fully understand the level of encryption bitlocker does.
I use Windows 10 and only have a C: drive which just got encrypted per the company policies.

Will this hinder my ability to share locally created docs (e.g. my office files) with my collaborators over email or fileshares?

e.g. if I create locally a doc file, which will then be encrypted, and put it in an email or upload it to an ftp, does it automatically becomes "un-encrypted" and as such, readable by others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No, it will not.

Bitlocker encrypts your files when your PC is turned off. That means if your PC is turned off and someone would steal it, your documents should be safe, assuming your Bitlocker password is strong.

Once you turn your PC back on and type your Bitlocker password, you can use it normally, as if Bitlocker was not present at all.

Comment: Given the amount of reputation you have I take this as granted :). Thank you for the quick answer.

Comment: It's not the reputation, you can verify this information yourself. Wikipedia's article about [BitLocker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitLocker) explains how it works and that it's fully transparent once the device is unlocked. Think of it like having a padlock on your bicycle: Once the padlock is off, the Bicycle isn't affected by it at all anymore and can be used normally.

Comment: I guess when someone explains it in plain text it's gold compared with more "official" documentation etc

Comment: To be fair, the Wikipedia article was largely written by, and for technical people.  It never actually mentions that bitlocker is designed to protect the files while the computer is off, or at best it's so buried in technical details you have to already know that to uncover it.  You and I know that's how all encryption full disk encryption works, but the vast majority of people don't really understand this.  That's why SE is here.  Honestly, the first sentence of the Wikipedia should be your first sentence.